# Capybara doesn't find select option

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm doing some scraping from a remote host, using Capybara with the Webkit driver (driving a form that uses JS).

The form is [here](http://www.assemblee-afe.fr/annuaire-des-membres).

The issue is I can't manage to select options by text, Capybara says it can't find them. E.g :

```
select("AICARDI René", from: "nom_message_annuaire")
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find option "AICARDI René"
```

The option exists. What gives?

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that the tag looks like `<option value="24">AICARDI&nbsp;René</option>` Could this weird behaviour be because of the nbsp;?

Comment: @AhmedAeonAxan: actually, I had tried adding the &nbsp; and now I found something that works, will post answer. Anyway, thanks for checking it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the `&nbsp;` inside the option's text.

I solved it with:

```
select(Nokogiri::HTML("AICARDI&nbsp;Réné").text, from: "nom_message_annuaire")
```

Comment: I would + 50 this if I could. How did you find it?